# Удаленная синхронизация

Tags: windows, синхронизация

В сети есть сервера с разными задачами. Часть из них должна отвечать за актуальность копий данных (просто файлы) между другими серверами. То есть управляющий сервер копирует (синхронизирует) данные с одного сервера на другой. Вопрос, как осуществить синхронизацию так, чтобы трафик шел между синхронизируемыми серверами, не затрагивая управляющий сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какое средство используется для синхронизации? FTP умеет удаленно копировать файлы между двумя серверами. Посмотрите статейку в [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FXP#FXP)

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять и удаленно запустить на одном из серверов батник, который и будет синхронизироваться. Удаленный запуск батника провести через PSExec и еще наверняка PowerShell что-то подобное содержит в себе.